# If Cells in column A equal cells in column A on other workbook copy that row

Tags: vba, excel

I've been stuck on this for ages, it seems relatively simple in my head but I cant get it to work.. So what I need is say if I have a cell in  workbook1 equals Bob, if that cell is in the same column in another workbook, copy that row..

So example.. if Bob in column A workbook1 is found in Column A workbook2 copy whatever is in the column b,c,d,e on bobs row into workbook2..

I could get it to work for singular ones easily but its for 500+ entries.

I've tried using arrays here is what I have got so far (the code is currently in a button on workbook1)

```
 Dim owb As Workbook
  Dim test1(500) As String, test2(500) As String, test3(500) As String, test4(500) As String 


With Application
    .DisplayAlerts = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

 fpath = "\Work\new location\test subject.xlsx" 'file location
   Set owb = Application.Workbooks.Open(fpath) 'open file
For i = 1 To 500 'for each I 


test1(i) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Allsites").Cells(i, 1).Value
test2(i) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Allsites").Cells(i, 8).Value
test3(i) = owb.Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 1).Value
test4(i) = owb.Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 2).Value 'declare locations

If test3(i) = test1(i) Then
test2(i) = test4(i)
End If
Next
```

Comment: One way:  Iterate through Col A of `Allsites` using the `Range.Find` method where `Range` is `owb.Worksheets("Sheet2").Columns(1)`.  If you find something, then put that information into a collection (or an array or on the destination worksheet).

Answer (score 0):

In the example above, you're checking for a match in the exact cell (eg the value in A5 is the same as the one in A5), so I've assumed the same in the code below. 
    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
    Dim destinationSheet As Worksheet
    Dim columnNumber As Integer

```
Set sourceSheet = Worksheets("Sheet3")
Set destinationSheet = Worksheets("Sheet2")

Dim sourceArr() As Variant
Dim destArr() As Variant
sourceArr = sourceSheet.Range("A1:E500")
destArr = destinationSheet.Range("A1:E500")

For i = 1 To 500 'for each I
    If destArr(i, 1) = sourceArr(i, 1) Then
        For columnNumber = 2 To 5
            destArr(i, columnNumber) = sourceArr(i, columnNumber)
        Next
    End If

Next
destinationSheet.Range("A1:A500").Value = destArr
```

There is a nice article about transferring data between arrays and worksheet ranges at http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx. Working with an array and writing the whole array in one go will be quicker than writing the value of each cell individually.

Update:
If the data can be in any row on the source spreadsheet, you can use Find to search for it. This may be quite a bit slower:

```
For i = 1 To 500 'for each I
    Dim found As Range

    Set found = searchRange.Find(destArr(i, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
    If Not found Is Nothing Then
        For columnNumber = 2 To 5
            destArr(i, columnNumber) = found.Offset(0, columnNumber - 1)
        Next
    End If
Next
```

You may want to consider using a VLookup function in the worksheet rather than using VBA.

Comment: Yeah sorry Jane I should of made it clear, it might not equal the same cell.. so bob in workbook 1 could be in cell A5, then in the second workbook A12... I will give the article a read and see if I can pull anything out to help me.